# Jmeter regular expression extractor in hidden value

Tags: jmeter

I have a hidden code from which I am trying extract the hidden field- 320365

```
<fieldset class="inputs"><ol></ol></fieldset><input id="activity_id" name="activity[approval_processor][approvals_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="320365" />
```

and I tried -

```
[approvals_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

but even the Regex Tester is not showing the number 320365.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, you just need to escape `[` and `]` as they have a special meaning in RegEx:

```
\[approvals_attributes\]\[0\]\[id\]" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

Also if you know that the value is supposed to be a number, it might be better to limit it to numbers only:

```
\[approvals_attributes\]\[0\]\[id\]" type="hidden" value="([0-9]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

**\[approvals_attributes\]\[0\]\[id\]" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"**

or you can also use the simple eq

**type="hidden" value="(.+?)"**

you can also use the website - https://regex101.com/
   to write any regular expressions.